# Navigating the mat table elements with the up and down button angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material-table

[`enter image description here`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2LDs.png)

**I want to be able to navigate with the up and down buttons on the data I pulled from IOrder[] but my code scrolls with keyboard keys. I would be very grateful if you could help, thanks in advance.**

html code

```
<div>
    <input (keyup)="navigateUsingKey($event)"/>
    <div *ngFor="let orderItem of orderItems; let i = index;" >
    <div [class.activeSearchLink]="i === linkIndex">{{orderItem.name}}</div>  
</div>
```

.ts code

```
navigateUsingKey(event)
 {
      switch (event.keyCode) {
          case 38: // this is the ascii of arrow up
                    this.linkIndex--;
                  break;
          case 40: // this is the ascii of arrow down
                    this.linkIndex++;
                  break;
                  
      }
  }
```

Comment: Essentially you need to do the same thing when clicking the buttons. The click handler for the down button should decrement `this.linkIndex` and the click handler for the up button should increment it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.